# Weird showcase of stuff on the screen

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I'm trying to create this `div` that shows information of the Civilian and Vehicle the user put in. I created the HTML and CSS for it, it was working all fine until I added 2 `div`s to the mix. With the one `div`, it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxVcS.png), with 2 `div`s, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9I81.png). IDK what is happening here, really. When I add a background to everything, there is no white background where the giant gap is from "Information: " and "Civilian: ". To go with that, when I put the `width` of the 2 `div`s to `%49.99` and set the display to `inline-block`, it shows up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHcg5.png). IDK how to explain it, it just goes off of the screen into oblivion. I'm soo sorry if this is basic ass stuff to fix inside of my HTML/CSS, I have minor knowledge of either and I'm just trying to use jQuery to mess around with some stuff in there (basically edit the text). Here is my HTML/CSS code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="civinfo">
        <h1>Information</h1>
        <!-- CIV SIDE -->
        <div>
            <h2>Civilian: </h2>
            <span><h3>Name: </h3><p id="civname">None, None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Warrant: </h3><p id="civwarrant">None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Citations: </h3><p id="civcit">None</p></span>
        </div>
        <!-- VEH SIDE -->
        <div>
            <h2>Vehicle: </h2>
            <span><h3>Plate: </h3><p id="vehplate">None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Stolen: </h3><p id="vehstolen">None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Registered: </h3><p id="vehregi">None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Insured: </h3><p id="vehinsured">None</p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#civinfo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #000000;
    width: 35%;
    height: 30%;
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#civinfo h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: 8px;
}
#civinfo div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 45%;
    height: auto !important;
}
#civinfo div h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#civinfo div h3 {
    display: inherit;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
#civinfo div span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
}
#civinfo div p {
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    display: inherit;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: #bbbbbb;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Also, don't worry about the `display: none;` on the `#civinfo` tag in the CSS, that's edited later in the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.content-wrapper{
display:flex;
}
.content-wrapper > div{
width:50%;
}
.content-wrapper > div > span{
display:flex;
}
h1{
display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="civinfo">
        <h1>Information</h1>

        <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- CIV SIDE -->
        <div>
            <h2>Civilian: </h2>
            <span><h3>Name: </h3><p id="civname">None, None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Warrant: </h3><p id="civwarrant">None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Citations: </h3><p id="civcit">None</p></span>
        </div>
        <!-- VEH SIDE -->
        <div>
            <h2>Vehicle: </h2>
            <span><h3>Plate: </h3><p id="vehplate">None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Stolen: </h3><p id="vehstolen">None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Registered: </h3><p id="vehregi">None</p></span>
            <span><h3>Insured: </h3><p id="vehinsured">None</p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi just wrap both civilian and vechicle div into one div and display it as flex.Try above code.Some css modification is done.